# Диагностика CARP pfSense

Tags: pfsense

Два хоста с Netgate XG-7100 настроены для работы в HA режиме, добавлены правила в файрвол пропускать CARP, PFSYNC, ICMP и TCP:80

Синхронизация настроек проходит успешно с мастера на слейв.

Мастер постоянно находится в режиме BACKUP, а слейв в режиме MASTER.

Очень похож на случай описываемый на форуме 
https://forum.netgate.com/topic/91962/carp-triggered-on-the-backup-only-without-obvious-reason

Как проверить диагностировать сеть на наличие схожих VIP?

Answer (score 0):

Для тех кому может понадобится, серьезных проблем не было.

Установленная версия на обоих устройства 2.2.5 ( built on Tue Mar 24 15:25:53 EDT 2020)

"Проблема" заключалась в том, что первичный fw1 был в режиме технического обслуживания, что устанавливало `advskew=240` это можно было видеть на хосте подключенном к сети

```
tcpdump -s 0 -i any -T carp proto 112 

первичный

 CARPv2-advertise 36: vhid=120 advbase=1 advskew=240 authlen=7 counter=8885618383488395996

вторичный

 CARPv2-advertise 36: vhid=120 advbase=1 advskew=100 authlen=7 counter=3073201634108799142
```

Переведя устройство в полных рабочий режим проблема разрешилась.

Ссылки на форум которые помогли

- https://forum.netgate.com/topic/80092/resolved-carp-not-failing-back-and-other-weird-behaviour-on-pfsense-2-2/7
- https://forum.netgate.com/topic/80137/carp-not-working-after-upgrade-from-2-1-5-to-2-2-ii